# Core Bluetooth Framework: Issue in creating Descriptor with new UUID

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have created an application in IPhone that can act as a BLE Peripheral.
Currently i am using descriptor as explained in this question of stack overflow.
[How do you create a descriptor for a mutable characteristic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622608/how-do-you-create-a-descriptor-for-a-mutable-characteristic)

```
    var characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: charId, properties: charProperties, value: nil, permissions:CBAttributePermissions.Readable)
    let userDescriptionUuid:CBUUID = CBUUID(string:CBUUIDCharacteristicUserDescriptionString)
    var myDescriptor = CBMutableDescriptor(type:userDescriptionUuid, value:characteristicDetail["name"])
    characteristic.descriptors = [myDescriptor]
```

My question is more specific about how can i create a `CBMutableDescriptor` with unique UUID and associate it with any characteristic I want.This is what i am trying to do, if I use a new UUID for descriptor it is giving me error 'UUID "D1FE4DDF-61A7-47F6-81BA-29B223F34322" is not allowed'.

```
    var desId:CBUUID = CBUUID(string:"750CC1D4-3B8B-4E12-A50E-F39727ED78B6")
    var myDescriptor = CBMutableDescriptor(type: desId, value: 123)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a descriptor for a mutable characteristic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622608/how-do-you-create-a-descriptor-for-a-mutable-characteristic)

Comment: If you refer to the answer for the question you linked to you will see that you can't create an arbitrary descriptor type - only the presentation format and user description types are supported.

Comment: I am also facing same problem, Have you find any solution.